# arcgis: load kml files upto 80 megbytes total(10 megabytes per file)

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

Hi I am using Arcgis for JS version 4.9, I am trying to load upto 8 kml files(each file is about 10 megabytes).
The loading of the kml is passing successfully but the interaction(pan&zoom) with the map is very slow and not smooth. 
I have several questions regarding this issue:

1. Can Esri load such an amount of kml files? if not is there any other alternatives ?
2. Why in openlayers I can do it smoothly and in pure arcgis it more problematic?
3. Can I upload a RAW kml data and not diretly via hosting url?

I would appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Kml is a vector format. One option would be to generalize the geometry of the features. Also, you could decrease the precision of the coordinates. For instance, a coordinate in meters with 5-6 digit after the coma is not necessary for visualization in a web map. You can round it to the meter.

Finally, if by raw data you mean parsing and loading a kml from a string, that's not possible with the ArcGIS API. The kml/kmz must be a separate file accessible on the internet.

> The KMLLayer uses a utility service from ArcGIS.com, therefore your
>   kml/kmz files must be publicly accessible on the internet. If the
>   kml/kmz files are behind a firewall you must to set the
>   esriConfig.kmlServiceUrl to your own utility service (requires ArcGIS
>   Enterprise).

Source: [the KMLLayer documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-KMLLayer.html)